# Setting up Eclipse and xDebug for PHP debugging failed Windows 10

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

I don't know if I can be helped but maybe someone has an idea that will help me setting up Eclipse for PHP debugging. And before you are annoyed by "another" post on this topic, I already have researched the existing ones.
I set up XAMPP and it works fine. I checked the phpinfo() and it shows xDebug is working. I setup Eclipse Neon with the latest Java which was working too. Then I went to the preferences and set up the PHP web application. I used all the standards like port 9000 and break at first line of code. Whenever I executed a debug Eclipse gives me the feedback that it tries to establish a connection with the xdebug but stops at 48% and does not continue. Of course a debugging like that is not possible. Anyway after 4 days I thought I throw it out there and ask for ideas what I still could do. I even turned my firewall off without any success.
Any idea is welcome... I am about to give up...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but:

One thing to check is that you have in php.ini / phpinfo()

xdebug.remote_enable = On

After that it should work assuming the rest of the run configuration is ok. I had the same 48% issue.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but this was the first thing I did and that was on and all set. I switched to Atom which worked. I am not sure if I am going to go back to Eclipse. I like it but it was too much of a hassle to get it working.